# Processing data in text files

Tags: python, numpy

I have multiple text file in a directory. Each of these files contains 7 columns and 20 rows. The last column has 0 values in all rows at the beginning.
What i want to do is: I want to use the first three column of each txt file (line by line) to make some calćulation and store the result in the 7th column respectively line by line.
To clarify the structure of one txt file:

```
642.29 710.87 154.24 -0.50384 -0.17085 0.067804 0
641.57 711.98 154.42 -0.50681 -0.16978 0.06784  0
640.82 713.14 154.58 -0.50944 -0.1711 0.068266 0
639.72 714.53 154.59 -0.50496 -0.19229 0.057764 0
638.99 715.79 154.75 -0.50728 -0.18873 0.057795 0
638.18 717.13 154.96 -0.51024 -0.18653 0.057893 0
```

After the calculations are done the last column becomes with the new values as following and the txt file should be stored with the new values:

```
   642.29 710.87 154.24 -0.50384 -0.17085 0.067804 0
   641.57 711.98 154.42 -0.50681 -0.16978 0.06784 1.3352527850560352
   640.82 713.14 154.58 -0.50944 -0.1711 0.068266 2.725828205520504
   639.72 714.53 154.59 -0.50496 -0.19229 0.057764 3.1632005923493804
   638.99 715.79 154.75 -0.50728 -0.18873 0.057795 3.237582509147674
   638.18 717.13 154.96 -0.51024 -0.18653 0.057893 3.044767452434894
```

I did the process for one file. But how can i do it for multiple files? Open each file automatically, do some calculations on that file and store it.
Thanks

My code for one file:

```
import numpy as np
import os
Capture_period= 10
Marker_frames= 2000
Sampling_time = Capture_period/Marker_frames
coords = []
vel_list = [0] 
ins_vel_list=[0]
# Define a function to calculate the euclidean distance
def Euclidean_Distance(a, b):
    a = np.array(a)
    b = np.array(b)
    return np.linalg.norm(a-b)
def process(contents):   
    contents = first_source_data.tolist()
    # Extract the xyz coordiantes
    for i, item in enumerate(contents):
         coords.append([[float(x) for x in item[0:3]], i+1])
    print(coords)
    rang=range(len(coords))
    for i in rang:
        if i !=rang[-1]:
            Eucl_distance = Euclidean_Distance(coords[i][0], coords[i+1][0])
            vel = ((Eucl_distance / (Sampling_time*100)))# + " cm/sec"
            vel_list.append(vel)
            ins_vel=(vel_list[i]+vel_list[i+1])/2
            ins_vel_list.append(ins_vel)
            continue
        #del ins_vel_list[:]
        #print(ins_vel_list)

from glob import glob
filepaths = glob("/home/experiment/*.txt")

for path in filepaths:
    print(path)
    process(path)
```

Problems:

1. The first 4 lines in each file are not read!
2. The append list must be reseted before the new file
3. You can create three text files with the 7 columns and whatever rows to test it.
4. Each file consists of coordinates of motion (xyz) and (theta_x, theta_y,theta_z) and the last column is the instantaneous velocity which the average of the average velocities.
5. The first component of the last column should equal in all files to zero (because a t the staring time the velocity is zero).

Any helps or solutions is appreciated!

Comment: If you pass in the filename on the cli you can loop through all the files pretty easily with your shell

Comment: @Katreen please make sure the code in question is properly indented. Right now it wouldn't execute, and is pretty difficult to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your code in a function and make the function accept the path as argument, then call the function in a `for` loop iterating over the list of files.

E.g.:

```py
from glob import glob
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import distance

CAPTURE_PERIOD = 10
MARKER_FRAMES = 2000
SAMPLING_TIME = CAPTURE_PERIOD/MARKER_FRAMES


def get_euclidean_distance(a, b):
    a = np.array(a)
    b = np.array(b)
    return np.linalg.norm(a - b)

def make_chunks(lst, n):
    for i in range(0, len(lst), n):
        yield lst[i : i+n]

def write_in_chunks(f, lst, n):
    for chunk in make_chunks(lst, n):
        f.write(" ".join(str(val) for val in chunk) + "\n")

def process_file(filepath):
    """Process a single file.

    :param filepath: path to the file to process
    """

    # Load data from file
    with open(filepath) as datafile: 
        contents = [line.split() for line in datafile]

    # Define an empty list for coordinates
    coords = []

    # Set the first component in the velocity vector to 0 in velocity_list
    vel_list = [0] 
    inst_vel_list=[0]

    # Extract the xyz coordiantes
    for i, item in enumerate(contents):
        coords.append([[float(x) for x in item[0:3]], i+1])
        
    # Calculate the euclidean distance and the speed using the previous coordinates system
    rang = range(len(coords))
    for i in rang:
        if i != rang[-1]:
            eucl_distance = get_euclidean_distance(coords[i][0], coords[i+1][0])
            vel = ((eucl_distance / (SAMPLING_TIME*100)))# + " cm/sec"
            vel_list.append(vel)
            inst_vel = (vel_list[i]+vel_list[i+1])/2
            inst_vel_list.append(inst_vel)
            continue
    for i, item in enumerate(contents):
        item[-1] = inst_vel_list[i]
    contents = np.ravel(contents)

    with open(filepath, "w") as f:
        write_in_chunks(f, contents, 7)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    filepaths = glob("/home/experiment/*.txt")
    for path in filepaths:
        process(path)
```

Comment: The problem is in the : inst_vel_list.append(inst_vel). All files will be added to same list. I use that list to write the new values into the last column in the corresponding txt file. When a new file comes, it will be added to that list as well. So any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: I don't get what you mean right now. I understood that you have figured out how to update the last column, but you just don't know how to run it for multiple files. Can you please revisit your question if you have any other problems? Also, please fix the indentation of your code, right now it's hard to guess how it's supposed to work.

Comment: I modify the code as well as the description to make it clear. Please test it on your system after creating three txt files with different coordinates (random). to know what i mean

Comment: Okay I have updated the answer, now it should work. It took me a while to figure out what your actual code is though, and I mostly used the previous, badly indented version. The code you updated the question with today is weird and definitely doesn't work - please revert it to the previous version, just fix the indentation. Regarding why it still didn't work when you put the stuff into a function: that's because you didn't put **all** of it in the function, specifically the `vel_list` and `inst_vel_list` and `coords` have to be inside, so they get re-initialized for every file.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works perfectly. I spent two days on it to figure out how can i solve it. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Hey Czaporka, Since you are familiar with this code. I want to modify it in away that  each velocity component (Vx,Vy,Vz) should be written in the columns 7,8,9 respectively instead of calculating the magnitude of this three component. I modified my code to calculate these velocity components in the euclidean distance and i add empty lists for (vx,vy,vz). I don't know if i can upload my code here as an extented version so you can have a look. My problem is,  the Write in chunks function deals with one column and when i repeat the for loop as well as the function calling i got weird results.

Comment: Have you tried increasing the 7 in `write_in_chunks(f, contents, 7)` to match the new number of columns? If that doesn't work then I'm not sure either about the best way to share your code. Options include asking a new question, adding a new section to this question (normally not preferable but this one sounds pretty generic already), or just sharing a link to some pastebin.